# Laravel Href to external site from database link

Tags: laravel

I have created a blade.php file that creates a list of customers(with their names, social media accounts, date added, etc.) from my database. I am having trouble being able to click on the social media icons and have it take you directly to their social media pages. I am looking to have an href on the icon that directs you to their page depending on the person. Any idea as to how to take the url from the database for each person and use it as the href on the social media icon. I currently can send them to the main social media account page(facebook, twitter, linkedin) but I cant get it to send them directly to the persons page.

```
<tr v-else v-for="lead in leads.data" :key="lead.id">
     <td class="social-buttons">
         <span v-if="lead.hasFacebook"><a href="$lead['facebook_url']" target="_blank" class="fa fa-facebook-square"></a></span>
         <span v-if="lead.hasTwitter"><a href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank" class="fa fa-twitter-square"></a></span>
         <span v-if="lead.hasLinkedin"><a href="https://linkedin.com" target="_blank" class="fa fa-linkedin-square"></a></span>
     </td>
```

Comment: Could you show **all** the relevant code please?

Comment: @Jackowski Just edited the question and added a chunk of code

Comment: How are you storing the `social media accounts` on the database?

Comment: @Jackowski They are allowed to connect facebook, twitter, and linkedin. when connected, it is saved in the DB under facebook_url, twitter_url, or linkedin_url. from there I want to be able to call them from that column and populate the href

Answer (score 0):

Bind the `href` html attribute to the `lead` values with `v-bind:href` or simply `:href`:

```
<span v-if="lead.hasFacebook"><a :href="lead.facebook_url" target="_blank" class="fa fa-facebook-square"></a></span>
<span v-if="lead.hasTwitter"><a :href="lead.twitter_url" target="_blank" class="fa fa-twitter-square"></a></span>
<span v-if="lead.hasLinkedin"><a :href="lead.linkedin_url" target="_blank" class="fa fa-linkedin-square"></a></span>
```